# Why the height difference between a textbox and a surronding span?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is there a reported difference in element heights given the following html?

```
<span id="spanner" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;"><input type="text" /></span>
```

When you ask for the height of the text box you'll get 16px.  The height of the span is reported as 19px (usually, IE says 22px).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the parent element factors in the pixels for the border, padding, and margins of the textbox.

Comment: That was it exactly.  Reset the padding and border to zero and they both report the same.  Thank you.

Comment: The IE box model is different from all other browsers. The width is total, including borders margin and padding, as opposed to the others where the borders margin and padding are in addition to the element.

Answer (score 1):

The input element will have a default border and padding, that may differ from browser to brower. Try removing that:

```
<input type="text" style="padding: 0; border: 0" />
```

Try inspecting the element with Firebug in Firefox to see the effective padding/margin/border of elements. With your example, you'll see that the text field has a 2px border and a 1px padding at the top and at the bottom.

Comment: ... and that's why * {margin:0; padding:0;} is a good idea :)

Comment: I also try to incorporate a reset style sheet that takes care of all the elements.